# How to verify that Google PubSub is hitting my endpoint and not another actor

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a fully functional endpoint that will receive a POST request from a PubSub subscription when a change has been detected in a user's Gmail inbox. Inside of the endpoint, I can successfully extract everything I need for my purposes.

The problem is that I have no idea who is actually hitting my endpoint. A bad actor could just pass me the same payload that Gmail would.

Is there a way for me to verify that the payload that I'm receiving is actually from Google/Gmail/PubSub?

On the Gmail side:
It seems the payload that is sent to my endpoint is unable to be changed and will always be of the form as detailed here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

On the PubSub side:
You can create your own topic and add key/value pairs as custom attributes to it, but it seems I wouldn't be able to modify the payload that Gmail is publishing to my topic. 
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher

Any insight would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested way to do this is to include a secret as a url parameter for your endpoint.  You could then reject any urls which do not include this secret.
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq#security

This could be configured as part of your normal push endpoint when you set up a push subscription.

If you wish to add extra metadata to the provided gmail messages, you could always set up a cloud dataflow job or cloud function as a subscriber directly from the gmail topic, and republish on a second topic which your external endpoint will read from.

-Daniel

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel! This is exactly what I needed.